# How to read multiple number from a text file

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

So this is my code and I keep getting segmentation faults.
How can I format this code to read a set of numbers from a file?

My input looks like this: 82, 46, 71, 56, 44, 12, 100 62, 67, 64, 65, 62, 39, 68 68, 90, 78, 57, 76, 45, 82 etc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    int line[7];
    int store = 0, read;

    if(!input)
    {
        printf("Error: Filename \"input.txt\" not found!\n");
    }

    store = 0;
    while(fscanf(input, "%d", &read) != EOF)
    {            
        line[store] = read;                 
        store++;
    }

    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6]); 
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What's the file format? Check that `store < 7` in your loop, and if `input` is `NULL`, not only print an error message, also `exit(1)`. And if `fscanf` fails to read an `int` without getting an input error, its return value will be 0, so check `fscanf(...) == 1`.

Comment: There seems to be no guard in the for loop preventing you from overflowing line[]. What if there are more than 7 numbers in your file?

Comment: Okay thanks! My input looks like this:

82, 46, 71, 56, 44, 12, 100
62, 67, 64, 65, 62, 39, 68
68, 90, 78, 57, 76, 45, 82
etc.

This help my case at all? (Also, if you know, how do I read the next line and so on?)

Comment: Oh, well there are lines of seven integers per line there but I don't know why I can't show it like that.

Comment: The commas are in the file? Then your `fscanf` will never manage to consume the first comma and return 0 until the programme segfaults because `store` is 1347 or whatever.

Comment: Ohhhhh so take out the commas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your while loop condition into:

```
while( store < sizeof(line)/sizeof(int) && fscanf(input, "%d", &read) != EOF)
```

looks like you have more numbers in the input then you have space for.

Comment: So this will prevent my line[] from overflowing?